# tf.data pipeline design for optimized performance

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to TensorFlow and I would like to know of there is any specific order to set the dataset using tfdata. For example:

```
    data_files = tf.gfile.Glob("%s%s%s" % ("./data/cifar-100-binary/", self.data_key, ".bin"))
    data = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(data_files, record_bytes=3074)
    data = data.map(self.load_transform)
    if self.shuffle_key:
        data = data.shuffle(5000)

    data = data.batch(self.batch_size).repeat(100)
    iterator = data.make_one_shot_iterator()
    img, label = iterator.get_next()
    # label = tf.one_hot(label, depth=100)
    print('img_shape:', img.shape)
```

In this case I read the data then shuffle the data followed by batch and repeat specifications. With this method my computer's RAM increases by 2%

and then I tried one more method:

```
    data_files = tf.gfile.Glob("%s%s%s" % ("./data/cifar-100-binary/", self.data_key, ".bin"))
    data = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(data_files, record_bytes=3074)
    data = data.map(self.load_transform)
    data = data.batch(self.batch_size).repeat(100)
    if self.shuffle_key:
        data = data.shuffle(5000)
    iterator = data.make_one_shot_iterator()
    img, label = iterator.get_next()
    # label = tf.one_hot(label, depth=100)
    print('img_shape:', img.shape)
```

so with this case when I first specify the batch size, repeat and then shuffle the RAM utilization increases by 40% (I do not know why) it would be great if someone helps me figure that out. 
So is there a sequence which I should always follow to define the dataset in tensorflow using tf.data ?

Comment: Check out the [input pipeline performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets) to get a little bit more background in to designing optimized data pipelines!

Comment: @kvish aah great thank you for the link it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The memory usage increases because you are shuffling batches instead of single records.

`data.shuffle(5000)` will fill a buffer of `5000` elements, then sample randomly from the buffer to produce the next element.

`data.batch(self.batch_size)` changes the element type from single records to batches of records. So if you call `batch` before `shuffle`, the shuffle buffer will contain `5000 * self.batch_size` records instead of just `5000`.

The order of calling `shuffle` and `batch` will also affect the data itself. Batching before shuffling will result in all elements of a batch being sequential.

`batch` before `shuffle`:

```
>>> dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(12)
>>> dataset = dataset.batch(3)
>>> dataset = dataset.shuffle(4)
>>> print([element.numpy() for element in dataset])
[array([ 9, 10, 11]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8])]
```

`shuffle` before `batch`:

```
>>> dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(12)
>>> dataset = dataset.shuffle(4)
>>> dataset = dataset.batch(3)
>>> print([element.numpy() for element in dataset])
[array([1, 2, 5]), array([4, 7, 8]), array([0, 3, 9]), array([ 6, 10, 11])]
```

Usually shuffling is done before batching to avoid all elements in the batch being sequential.